# OData continuation link is invalid

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Repro: Open https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Posts

Observe: continuation link has port 20000:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://odata.stackexchange.com:20000/stackoverflow/atom/Posts?$skiptoken=62" />
```

Expected: no port, just odata.stackexchange.com

Same applies to `<id>` element.

Comment: I am seeing same problem today

Comment: :) again any patch to fix this would be more than welcome

Comment: @waffles No longer reproducible, after moving to new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed after [moving to new server](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/).